# Choose window manager from command line

Tags: unity, gnome, login, 15.10, lxde

I didn't know what Window Manager I should use: I like both Gnome/Unity of Ubuntu and LXDE of Lubuntu: sometimes I need lightweight (example maximize battery - Lubuntu), sometimes I need (want) Unity graphical design and Gnome apps.

So, I have Ubuntu. I have installed lxde by

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

Now, to improve boot speed, I don't want to use graphical login but command line login. 
After login, I want to start the X server with the Window Manager I need in that moment: Gnome/Unity or LXDE.

What I have to do to start from terminal gnome/unity or lxde? I need to know both instruction! Thank you!!

Comment: You should be able to choose the DE that you want at log in.  I believe that if you are in Unity and want to move to LXDE all you need to do is log out and then log in with LXDE.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome, Unity and LXDE are desktop environments. However, they are not attached to the display manager(which starts the X servers, user sessions and greeter). Therefore, you can download a console display manager to have command-line login but graphical desktop.

I'd suggest you to use CDM ([download link](https://github.com/ghost1227/cdm/zipball/master)).
Just download the zip file from the link and do the following commands:

```
unzip ghost1227-cdm-[version].zip
cd ghost1227-cdm-[version]/
sudo ./install.sh
```

To autostart cdm when you log in your account, copy the content of /usr/share/doc/cdm/profile.sh to the tail of your shell profile (~/.profile, etc.).